# Hair Geometry Nodes not visible / does not render

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, hair

I would like to create a hair geometry node setup with procedural distribution.

I got it to work with an image density mask (top left) where I got those nice stripes. I want to do the same with a wave texture procedurally and the curves appear in the right place, however I found no way to apply a thickness/geometry to the hair, so it won't render.

Do you have any ideas for this?

[image]

**Update**:

Here are two screenshots with the *Set Curve Profile* node (*not* rendering):

[image: test with set curve profile]

And Curve To Mesh Node (*does* render):
[image: test with curve to mesh node]

Comment: What do you mean by *"I found no way to apply a thickness/geometry to the hair, so it won't render."*? The (hair) curves of the *Curves* object are rendered natively by Eevee and Cycles and do not need geometry (=faces). Set the curve radius with a *Set Curve Radius* node to control the thickness of the curves. There is also a *Set Hair Curve Profile* node group in the *Add Node* menu (*Hair > Write > ...*) with more options. -- If you want to export them you need to convert the curves into a mesh with a *Curve To Mesh* node. This will create geometry with faces.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I tried this and it still won't render for some reason. If I add a Curve to Mesh node, it will show, but then I have all the geometry that i did not want. If I just add the Set Curve Radius node, it just won't change show up.

Comment: Thanks for the new screenshots. I've added them to your question.  This is a Q&A site and works differently than a forum. If you post them in the answer section the post will be removed because it's actually not a real answer but a follow-up info. It should be added as an edit in order to keep the page structure clean (one question, multiple answers).

Comment: Have a look at the *Set Curve Radius* and *Curve to Mesh* nodes that you have added. They have a little "[i]" icon at the top right corner. That's an error message. Hover the mouse cursor over it to see the message. My guess is that the *Geometry* input in your node tree not only contains *curve* data but also *mesh* data. This causes problems. You either need to make sure you only have curve data -or- you need to split the data types. If you tab into the *Generate Hair Curves* node group you will see a *Separate Components* and a *Join Geometry* node and the group only handles the curves.

Answer (score 0):

Hair curves renders as hair curves only in hair object:

[image]

If you make hair curves on object itself, curves will be interpreted as usual curves, that (if they have not converted to mesh) is not rendered.

So the problem is how to transfer data from mesh to hair object, I suppose. This can be done using sample nearest surface point node:

[image]